# Mouse highlighting in a Spinbox triggers unknown events

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent, spinbox

I have a Python Tkinter application which has some typical numeric spinbox widgets. When the spinbox is manipulated with arrow keys or data is simply entered, everything is normal. But if a mouse is used to highlight any of the numbers, some unknown (to me) events are firing which are causing problems - field validation events, field refreshes, etc..

Can anyone point me to documentation which describes what may be happening under the covers?

I've tried inhibiting the various mouse motion events, but that has no effect.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] and include it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some links to documentation on the Internet.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html
https://tkdocs.com/pyref/spinbox.html

Please provide code snippets next time because I don't know what exactly your problem is.

Comment: How is this helpful and why don't you write a comment instead of posting an answer to a question you don't understand ?

Comment: He asked for documentation and i gave him some links